# Does FFT neccessary to find peaks and pits on audio files

Tags: signal-processing, audio

I'm able to read a wav files and its values. I need to find peaks and pits positions and their values. First time, i tried to smooth it by `(i-1 + i + i +1) / 3` formula then searching on array as `array[i-1] > array[i] & direction == 'up' --> pits` style solution but because of noise and other reasons of future calculations of project, I'm tring to find better working area. Since couple days, I'm researching FFT. As my understanding, fft translates the audio files to series of sines and cosines. After fft operation the given values is `a0`'s and `a1`'s for `a0 + ak * cos(k*x) + bk * sin(k*x)  which k++ and x++` as this picture

http://zone.ni.com/images/reference/en-XX/help/371361E-01/loc_eps_sigadd3freqcomp.gif

My question is, does fft helps to me find peaks and pits on audio? Does anybody has a experience for this kind of problems?

Comment: I would recommend asking something like this on http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to estimate the relative loudness/quietness of an audio digital sample at a given point.

For this estimation, you don't need to use FFT. However your method of averaging the signal does not produce the appropiate picture neither.

The digital signal is the value of the audio wave at a given moment. You need to find the overall amplitude of the signal at that given moment. You can somewhat see it as the local maximum value for a given interval around the moment you want to calculate. You may have a moving max for the signal and get your amplitude estimation.

At a 16 bit sound sample, the sound signal value can go from 0 up to 32767. At a 44.1 kHz sample rate, you can find peaks and pits of around 0.01 secs by finding the max value of 441 samples around a given t moment.

```
max=1;
for (i=0; i<441; i++) if (array[t*44100+i]>max) max=array[t*44100+i];
```

then for representing it on a 0 to 1 scale you (not really 0, because we used a minimum of 1)

```
amplitude = max / 32767;
```

or you might represent it in relative dB logarithmic scale (here you see why we used 1 for the minimum value)

```
dB = 20 * log10(amplitude);
```

Comment: dB = 10 * log_10(amplitude) is not the correct formula. Please see my answer for the correct formula.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you are trying to do, which you haven't really made clear. "finding the peaks and pits" is one thing, but since there might be various reasons for doing this there might be various methods. You already tried the straightforward thing of actually looking for the local maximum and minima, it sounds like. Here are some tips:

1. you do not need the FFT.
2. audio data usually swings above and below zero (there are exceptions, including 8-bit wavs, which are unsigned, but these are *exceptions*), so you must be aware of positive and negative values. Generally, large positive and large negative values carry large amounts of energy, though, so you want to count those as the same.
3. due to #2, if you want to average, you might want to take the average of the absolute value, or more commonly, the average of the square. Once you find the average of the squares, take the square root of that value and this gives the [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square), which is related to the power of the signal, so you might do something like this is you are trying to indicate signal loudness, intensity or approximate an analog meter. The average of absolutes may be more robust against extreme values, but is less commonly used.
4. another approach is to simply look for the peak of the absolute value over some number of samples, this is commonly done when drawing waveforms, and for digital "peak" meters. It makes less sense to look at the minimum absolute.
5. Once you've done something like the above, yes you may want to compute the log of the value you've found in order to display the signal in dB, but make sure you use the right formula. 10 * log_10( amplitude ) is *not* it. Rule of thumb: usually when computing logs from amplitude you will see a 20, not a 10. If you want to compute dBFS (the amount of "headroom" before clipping, which is the standard measurement for digital meters), the formula is -20 * log_10( |amplitude| ), where amplitude is normalize to +/- 1. Watch out for amplitude = 0, which gives an infinite headroom in dB.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is take dy/dx, which can getapproximately by just scanning through the wave and and subtracting the previous value from the current one and look at where it goes to zero or changes from positive to negative

in this code I made it really brief and unintelligent for sake of brevity, of course you could handle cases of dy being zero better, find the 'centre' of a long section of a flat peak, that kind of thing. But if all you need is basic peaks and troughs, this will find them.

```
lastY=0;

bool goingup=true;

for( i=0; i < wave.length; i++ ) {
    y = wave[i];
    dy = y - lastY;

    bool stillgoingup = (dy>0);

    if( goingup != direction ) {
       // changed direction - note value of i(place) and 'y'(height)
       stillgoingup = goingup;
    }
 }
```